# How to parse a text file with the below pattern

Tags: python

I am trying to parse the text file which is listed like below.

```
 BIOSReleaseDate = 04/13/2016
 BIOSVersionString = 2.1.5
 BaseBoardChassisSlot = Slot 08
 BatteryRollupStatus = 1
 BladeGeometry = 0
```

with this sort of text file having around 40 to 50 lines.  I am able to read this output to a text file. From there I am stuck on how to split LHS value and RHS value.

Comment: show us your code and what you have tried

Comment: Searching for "Python string split" will lead you to [str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: f=open('C:/Users/praveen_kumar10/My Documents/python programs/winRM.txt', 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    d = {} #optional dictionary to store data
    for l in lines:
        parts = l.split('=') #stores the LHS and RHS of the line in a list
        lhs = parts[0]
        rhs = parts[1]
        d[lhs] = rhs #store data in dictionary
        print d
        f.close()

Comment: @user3232223 please edit your question to add that code and explain what it should do / what you expect it to do as well as what it did instead.

Comment: actually i need to save the word LHS section and RHS section in a list or dictionary by eliminating or truncating "="

Answer (score 1):

Try the .split() method

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    d = {} #optional dictionary to store data
    for l in lines:
        parts = l.split(' = ') #stores the LHS and RHS of the line in a list
        lhs = parts[0]
        rhs = parts[1]
        d[lhs] = rhs #store data in dictionary
```

Comment: I tried this logic. But print of dictionary d is returning blank list. the below is the code snippet. f=open('C:/Users/praveen_kumar10/My Documents/python programs/winRM.txt', 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    d = {} #optional dictionary to store data
    for l in lines:
        parts = l.split('=') #stores the LHS and RHS of the line in a list
        lhs = parts[0]
        rhs = parts[1]
        d[lhs] = rhs #store data in dictionary
        print d
        f.close()

Comment: I tested my code, it works. I'm not sure what your problem is. Try printing `l` at every iteration to make sure the lines look how they're supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

The [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method might come in handy here. You need to iterate over the lines.

```
>>> string = "name=foo"
>>> print string.split("=")
["name", "foo"]
```